# Проблема со скоростью решения задачи SciPy.Minimaze (SLSQP)

Tags: python, scipy

Я пытаюсь написать решатель для производственной задачи, который должен распределять рабочее время по дням и рабочим местам, минимизируя переработку. В водных данных у меня 6000 переменных и 7000 ограничений.
Он работает неприлично медленно.
Есть ли какие либо способы ускорить код?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from datetime import datetime

BD = pd.read_excel('Загрузка.xlsx', sheet_name='БД')
PZ = pd.read_excel('Загрузка.xlsx', sheet_name='ПЗ')
TIME = pd.read_excel('Загрузка.xlsx', sheet_name='Время работы')

x0 = np.zeros(n)

#Определяем индексы BD для каждой стоки TIME
TIME_ind = []
for n_Price in TIME.index:
    tab_BD_ind = BD[(BD['День'] == TIME.at[n_Price, 'День']) & (BD['Рабочий центр пр-во'] == TIME.at[n_Price, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    TIME_ind.append(tab_BD_ind)

#Целевая функция
def objective(x):
    res = 0
    for n_Price in TIME.index:
        res += sum(x[TIME_ind[n_Price]] * TIME.at[n_Price, 'Цена часа работы']) #Стоимость работы
        res += max(sum(x[TIME_ind[n_Price]]) - TIME.at[n_Price, 'Опт загрузка'],0) * TIME.at[n_Price, 'Цена часа переработки']
    return res

#Определяем индексы для производства и потребления деталей ПЗ
PZ_ind_prvo = []
PZ_ind_potr = []
for n_PZ in PZ.index:
    tab_BD_ind_prvo = BD[(BD['Номенклатура пр-во'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Номенклатура']) & (BD['Характеристика пр-во'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Характеристика']) 
                    & (BD['Рабочий центр пр-во'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    tab_BD_ind_potr = BD[(BD['Номенклатура потр-е'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Номенклатура']) & (BD['Характеристика потр-е'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Характеристика']) 
                    & (BD['Рабочий центр потр-е'] == PZ.at[n_PZ, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    PZ_ind_prvo.append(tab_BD_ind_prvo)
    PZ_ind_potr.append(tab_BD_ind_potr)

#Добавляем ограничения по ПЗ
for n_PZ in PZ.index:
    constrants.append({'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x, n_PZ = n_PZ: sum(x[PZ_ind_prvo[n_PZ]] * BD.loc[PZ_ind_prvo[n_PZ], 'Объем производства в час'].values.tolist()) 
                       - sum(x[PZ_ind_potr[n_PZ]] * BD.loc[PZ_ind_potr[n_PZ], 'Объем потребления в час'].values.tolist()) 
                      - PZ.loc[n_PZ, 'ПЗ']})

#Определяем индексы для остатков (производство, потребление)
ost_ind_prvo = []
ost_ind_potr = []

tab_nom = BD[['День','Номенклатура пр-во', 'Характеристика пр-во', 'Рабочий центр пр-во']].drop_duplicates().reindex()

for n_nom in tab_nom.index:
    tab_BD_ind_prvo = BD[(BD['День'] <= tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'День']) & (BD['Номенклатура пр-во'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Номенклатура пр-во']) 
                        & (BD['Характеристика пр-во'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Характеристика пр-во']) 
                        & (BD['Рабочий центр пр-во'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    tab_BD_ind_potr = BD[(BD['День'] <= tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'День']) & (BD['Номенклатура потр-е'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Номенклатура пр-во']) 
                        & (BD['Характеристика потр-е'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Характеристика пр-во']) 
                        & (BD['Рабочий центр потр-е'] == tab_nom.at[n_nom, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    ost_ind_prvo.append(tab_BD_ind_prvo)
    ost_ind_potr.append(tab_BD_ind_potr)

#Добавляем ограничения по остатку
for n_ost in tab_nom.index:
    constrants.append({'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x, n_ost = n_ost: sum(x[ost_ind_prvo[n_ost]] * BD.loc[ost_ind_prvo[n_ost], 'Объем производства в час'].values.tolist()) 
                       - sum(x[ost_ind_potr[n_ost]] * BD.loc[ost_ind_potr[n_ost], 'Объем потребления в час'].values.tolist())})

#Определяем индексы для дней и станков
days_ind = []
tab_days = BD[['День', 'Рабочий центр пр-во']].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
for n_tab_day in tab_days.index:
    tab_24_ind = BD[(BD['День'] == tab_days.at[n_tab_day, 'День']) & (BD['Рабочий центр пр-во'] == tab_days.at[n_tab_day, 'Рабочий центр пр-во'])].index.values.tolist()
    days_ind.append(tab_24_ind)

#Добавляем ограничения по 24 часам
for n_days in tab_days.index:
    constrants.append({'type' : 'ineq', 'fun' : lambda x, n_days = n_days: (24 - sum(x[days_ind[n_days]]))})

#CALLBACK
n_iter = 0
def call_back(kx):
    global n_iter
    n_iter += 1
    print('n_iter: {0} time: {1} x: {2} fun: {3}'.format(n_iter , datetime.now(), sum(kx), objective(kx)))

#Решаем
solution = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=constrants, options={'maxiter' : 10}, callback = call_back)
```

Comment: Попробуйте: (1) применить другой метод минимизации. Например ’L-BFGS-B' или https://pypi.org/project/ipopt/ ...; (2) поискать аналитическую эмпирику для вашего "характерного случая".

Answer (score 0):

Это не совсем ответ, но гайдлайн. В комментариях такое писать неудобно, поэтому пишу ответом.

```py
#Целевая функция
def objective(x):
    res = 0
    for n_Price in TIME.index:
        res += sum(x[TIME_ind[n_Price]] * TIME.at[n_Price, 'Цена часа работы']) #Стоимость работы
        res += max(sum(x[TIME_ind[n_Price]]) - TIME.at[n_Price, 'Опт загрузка'],0) * TIME.at[n_Price, 'Цена часа переработки']
    return res
```

1. `TIME.at[n_Price, 'Цена часа работы']` - вынимать колонку из `DataFrame` - это долго. Вынесите это хотя бы в отдельную `Series` сразу: `TIME_Price = TIME['Цена часа работы']` и обращайтесь уже к ней как `TIME_Price[n_Price]`. Тоже самое с остальными двумя колонками, которые тут используются.
2. Используйте не питоновский `sum`, а метод датафрейма/серии, хотя я не уверен, что у вас там в данных, может на этом этапе и не сработает. Т.е. вместо `sum(a * b + c)` используйте `(a * b + c).sum()` и тоже самое с `max`.
3. Хорошо бы вообще уйти от объектов `Pandas` полностью в `Numpy`, но тогда пропадёт возможность обращаться к данным по нечисловым индексам, придётся перерабатывать концепцию.
4. Если получится уйти в `Numpy` и скорость всё ещё будет недостаточна, можно будет попробовать использовать декоратор `Numba.njit()` на функции `objective`, но это тоже может быть непросто, придётся поразбираться, как заставить его работать. Кстати, `Numba` будет хорошо работать и с простыми питоновскими списками, если не выйдет с `Numpy`, можно попробовать в эту сторону.

Ещё, наверное, что-то хорошо бы сделать с `constraints`, подозреваю, что там примерно те же проблемы, но не уверен, насколько сильно влияет рефакторинг ограничений на скорость всего процесса оптимизации.